# How can I schedule events to call up their own tkinter window and/or update the main one?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, scheduled-tasks

**Goal**:
I have an alert app, where I want to schedule events at various times. If there is a tkinter window open at that time, the scheduled job should update that window. Else, it should create a new window (that later scheduled events can update).

**Failed Approach 1**
I have tried having threads open and update the tkinter root window, but run into this error:
`Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread exit code -2147483645`. From what I've researched, tkinter mainloops shouldn't be called by threads. I am unclear how to achieve my task without this though, as the user should be able to close the window (which destroys the root). Which means later scheduled tasks will need to call a new `root.mainloop()`

**Failed Approach 2**
I have also tried inheriting from a `threading.Thread` class and doing

```
class App(threading.Thread)
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def callback(self):
        self.root.quit()

    def run(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.mainloop()
    def add_message(self):
        print(self.root) #Attribute error
```

However, this prevents later threads from updating it, as I get the error:
`AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'root'`
when I try to call it from other methods, such as `app.add_message()`.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: The error means `root` is not defined right, which means `self.run` is not getting run. Also keep in mind, `tkitner` does not fully support multithreading.

Comment: self.run works. So does self.callback. It's only self.add_message that seems to mysteriously lose the attribute. I'm assuming it has to do with the inheritance from threading, but I'm unsure.